# nested routes with static pages in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm currently rendering some static pages in my routes.rb as follows:

```
  get "home/index"
  get "about", to: "home#about"
  get "help", to: "home#help"
  get "news", to: "home#news"
  get "mobile", to: "home#mobile"
```

Under my "views" folder, I have a "home" folder that then contains "about.html", "help.html", etc.  I want to have a page "android" that appears nested under mobile, i.e.

```
/mobile/android
```

**How would I set this up in my routes, and where would I put the corresponding view?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually not a very good idea to handle static pages like this, but if you only need to add one page, then I would it so:

**config/routes.rb**

```
get "mobile/android", to: "home#mobile_android"
```

And add new `mobile_android.html` file in `home` folder, as you already did.

But again, it's not a great idea to handle static pages in rails like that.